# nbconvert Execute Jupyter notebook from Command Line output results

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

This question must've been asked before, but I couldn't find a right answer. I would like to run the Jupyter notebook from command line and save the result to certain files.

I got this running,

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python --execute mynotebook.ipynb >> mylog.out.log 2>&1
```

This command executes mynotebook.ipynb properly, but in the log file, it only contains 3 lines if the execution is successful.

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook mynotebook.ipynb to python
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python2
[NbConvertApp] Writing 1931 bytes to mynotebook.ipynb.py
```

If the notebook raises some exception, it will show the exception in the log file too. But where do I see the results of the notebook?

For example, in my notebook, I have

```
print 'hello world'
```

This output doesn't show in my command line interface or in the log file. Is there an approach or a parameter setting to keep the output into a log file? I would like to see the detailed results of mynotebook.ipynb.

Any thought? or any other better method than *jupyter nbconvert*?

---

Also, it that possiable to include the datetime into the log file? it would be very helpful to have the time included.

Comment: Have you tried it without "--to python" ?

Comment: @nitind yes, I did. Without '--to python', execution will convert ipynb to html file( which I believe html is the default ).

Comment: The output with `--execute` goes into the notebook. But if you convert it to a `.py` script file, that does not include output, so the output it's just generated is discarded again. Converting to a format like html or notebook will include the output. I don't think there's an option to send output to stdout, but if you look at the code it shouldn't be hard to hack sommething together.

Comment: @ThomasK thank you. you are right. I tried stdout to python but there will no output. If I use html or notebook, if will include output. Even thought the whole output file will include the converted code not pure results, it works for me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try --stdout and you have to convert to something like html to see output for example

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb --stdout --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python --ExecutePreprocessor.enabled=True
```

Comment: Thank you. The --stdout option works for outputing the converted code as long as the output results into a html file. Even though it is not totally clean, at least the output can be saved to some file. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't like this answer too much, since I have few message and a lot of code. Convertig is a big mess.